# Raspberry Pi VNC to shell

Tags: debian, vnc

I have a Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian Jessie) since yesterday and already installed some usefull tools - e.g. TightVNC. I configured it and it works fine, but now I want to stop my raspberry from booting into desktop mode. So if I connect over VNC I just want to see a shell window, like if I press "Ctrl-Alt-F1" for example.

Is there a way to configure my VNC to work like this? I already searched the web and didn't find something useful.. so please help me!

Comment: would ssh fit your needs?

Comment: Yes and no. I have a command-line program that I want to run permanently on my raspberry, which writes a lot to stdout.Let's say, I'm connecting over SSH with my MacBook, run the program, then disconnect. Then I connect again, how can I get the output of my program? That's not possible I think.

Comment: I would recommend using screen in top of ssh https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: daaaamn that works like a charm! thank you very much!

Comment: I wrote an answer with a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out TightVNC works over graphical mode, and often is cumbersome, slow and not practical.

As you refer that you want to deal with text output, you might want to ssh to the server, and use screen (a text-mode app) to manage/reconnect to long running tasks. If you use it judiciously, you may have multiple tasks running with the same account. Screen also allow to reconnect at any time from any place as long as login via ssh with the same account you used previously to launch the job.

Here you have a couple of links explain screen

https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/
http://www.cae.tntech.edu/help/systems/unix/screen

Initially you login with ssh and leave a job running. Any time you come back, logging with the same user, and you can reconnect with that job running

```
screen -r
```

And you are back to the screen you left.

As you get used to it, you will find out you can switch over multiple virtual screens with different key combinations.